# Is it possible to transfer a Project from an user to an organization?

Tags: github, project, organization

I've recently moved a repository from my account to an organization that I've created. I can't create any entries from my issues on the repository since. Is there a way to pass ownership of my Project to the Organization so I get back to creating entries on it for the stuff I want to do in the repository? I would rather not need to recreate my entries again, if possible.

I've tried searching for this before asking here and I've only found this [other, similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57984334/how-to-transfer-a-github-projects-from-one-repository-to-another?r=SearchResults&s=4%7C65.6347), that also wasn't answered.

Comment: What do you mean by "create entries from my issues" exactly?

Comment: Generally, you can transfer a repo from your personal account to an organization if you have the permission to create repos in that organization; see [here](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/creating-and-managing-repositories/transferring-a-repository#transferring-a-repository-owned-by-your-personal-account).

Comment: @BenjaminW. The question is not about repositories, but about projects. I transferred my repos just fine to the organization, but couldn't find a way to transfer my project. Issues on repositories you manage can be assigned to Projects, if you have one created. I was unable to turn the repository issues into tasks in the Project, neither I could transfer my Project from my account to my organization.

Comment: Oh, totally overlooked that! "Create entries" makes a lot more sense now... there's [this discussion](https://github.com/community/community/discussions/39826) asking about it, and there doesn't seem to be an official answer yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Benjamin mentioned, as of March 7th, 2023, there is currently no way to perform this action.

[Here is](https://github.com/community/community/discussions/39826) the community discussion tab about this, although unresolved.